# React Typescript: Loop over countries list to create a select input

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a list of countries keyed with the ISO code saved in countries.tsx...

```
// countries.tsx
export const COUNTRIES: { [x: string]: { [y: string]: string } } = {
  en: {
    AX: 'Aaland Islands',
    AF: 'Afghanistan',
    AL: 'Albania',
    DZ: 'Algeria',
    AS: 'American Samoa',
    AD: 'Andorra',
    },
};
```

I then import the above countries and get the language of the user from global

```
import { COUNTRIES } from '../../translations/countries';
const languages = COUNTRIES[global.language];
```

How do i then loop over countries to construct the select box?

```
<select name='country' value={country} onChange={onChange}>
    <option value=''>Select...</option>
    <option value='AX'>Aaland Islands</option>
    <option value='AF'>Afghanistan</option>
    <option value='AL'>Albania</option>
    <option value='DZ'>Algeria</option>
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
const COUNTRIES: { [x: string]: { [y: string]: string } } = {
  en: {
    AX: 'Aaland Islands',
    AF: 'Afghanistan',
    AL: 'Albania',
    DZ: 'Algeria',
    AS: 'American Samoa',
    AD: 'Andorra',
    },
};

const languages = COUNTRIES[global.language];

<select name='country' value={country} onChange={onChange}>
  <option key="" value="">Select...</option>
{
  Object
    .entries(languages)
    .map(([ key, display ]) => (
    <option key={key} value={key}>{display}</option>
  ))
}
</select>
```

[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) allows you to get the keys and values as an array of arrays, then you just use a map to iterate over the array

Comment: Side note, `Object.entries()` isn't supported in IE. You'd need to polyfill it

Comment: You can use Object.keys instead `Object.keys(obj).map(k=>{const display = obj[k] ...})`

Comment: with .keys I then get the error `Type 'string' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.ts(2569)` with `{Object.keys(countries).map(([key, display]) => (`